# Join two tables by finding max row first

Tags: mysql

I want to get data only for the max row for table m and join it to table l to find progress

Table(m)

```
   id  labref  activity
    ---------------------
    1    x       ab
    2    x       cd
    3    x       ef
    4    y       jk
    5    y       il
```

Table (l);

```
    id  activity  progress
    ---------------------
    1    ab       0
    2    cd       10
    3    ef       20
    4    jk       30
    5    il       40
```

When I run to get max row it works

```
select t1.* from m t1
left join m t2 on t1.labref = t2.labref
and t1.id < t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

But when i run the below query to add the progress

```
select t1.id, t1.labref, t1.activity, sp.progress from m t1,  l sp
left join m t2 on t1.labref = t2.labref
and sp.location = t1.activity
and t1.id < t2.id
where t2.id is null

The error is:  Unknown column 'sp.progress' in 'field list'
```

The result I am looking for is

```
id   labref   activity   progress
----------------------------------
3      x          ef       20
5      y          il       40
```

Any Suggestion guys, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax. In fact, avoid implicit syntax altogether

Comment: How would you rewrite the query?

Comment: With joins instead of commas - except that performance is so poor with this solution, that I'd use an uncorrelated subquery instead! But this is a good technique though.

Comment: @Strawberry Why is the performance poor? Could you provide a link? I'm not questioning it, just curious.

Comment: @abl I'm not sure I can - tried and tested I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT m.id, m.labref, m.activity, l.progress
    FROM (SELECT labref, MAX(id) as MaxId
              FROM m
              GROUP BY labref) q
        INNER JOIN m 
            ON q.MaxId = m.id
        INNER JOIN l
            ON m.activity = l.activity;
```